# How to compiling packages from source?

Tags: drbd

I need to install DRBD in a server without internet. (redhat 7.x)

It's a sad place where you can't use `yum`.....

You have to compile using the source.

So, I have the following questions:

1. Is it possible to install all the currently uploaded sources?
2. Do I need to install all 3 of **DRBD 9.x Linux Kernel Driver** / **DRBD 9.0.x Linux Kernel Driver** / **DRBD Utilities** ? If not, which one should I install?
3. What other libraries do I need to install?
4. If anyone has installed DRBD9 by source compile on RHEL 7.x, can you tell me how?

If you can answer the above questions, I would be very grateful.

thank you in advance

Comment: I searched and found these in the necessary libraries. ```gcc gcc-c++ make automake autoconf flex libxslt libxslt-devel kernel-devel kernel-headers rpm-build python-devel asciidoc fop inkscape unconv docbook2odf mathmlsvg dbus dbus-python pygobject2 po4a``` What do really need?

Answer (score 1):

I believe drdb is available in the EPEL repositories.
Compiling from source can be a royal PITA, but very easily doable and there are many articles on the internet you can find to help guide you through this.

However, if you really want to just use someone's packages, get EPEL repos setup on your RHEL machine(s) and use yum.

https://centos.pkgs.org/7/epel-x86_64/drbd-9.17.0-1.el7.x86_64.rpm.html

Comment: Thank you for answer. However, I would like to install on all Linux. So I want to install it as a tarball that can support various os. And the place to install is a place that has a closed network.